# How to remove a div after a second and make other one change in width in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-animate, settimeout

I need remove a div from DOM after 1 second, I found out how to hide using CSS, but the problem this divs stay in the DOM.

So how can remove this Div from DOM and make the other one be `width:100%` ?

**css**:

```
.header {
width:30%;
}

.sub-header {
width:70%;
}
```

**html**:

```
<div class="header">
 I need be removed not hided from DOM after 1 second
</div>

<div class="sub-header">
 I need be 100% after 1 second
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `setTimeout()` and apply the `animate()` as per your need.

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('.header').remove();
  $('.sub-header').animate({
                   width: '100%',
                   marginLeft: '40%'
              });  
}, 1000);
```

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  $('.header').remove();
  $('.sub-header').animate({
                   width: '100%',
                   marginLeft: '40%'
              });  
}, 1000);
```

```css
.header {
width:30%;
}

.sub-header {
width:70%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
 I need be removed not hided from DOM after 1 second
</div>

<div class="sub-header">
 I need be 100% after 1 second
</div>
```

Comment: Man! You answer well, but please add some stuff.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yeah man, I agree with you but I am still not expert in SO.

Comment: Ha ha... You don't need to be an expert, but basically, it is just that you need to add some info. Anyways, take your votes! :D

Comment: Yeah, I am trying and expecting more always :D

Comment: Ha ha ha... You already have one from me. Can't give you more. `:P`

Comment: But your overall profile is far ahead then me, so you can afford few still :P

Comment: By law, by design, a user can give only one vote to any post. `:(` I have no problem clicking it again, which makes it 4. LoL.

Comment: I am talking general, not saying you to click once again, even there is no reports that shows which user has clicked and which is still remained :)
Anyways Thanks for your advice, I will keep in mind and will try to reach around you in near future, I know it's tough competition :(

Comment: When you have the skills, it is a cake walk in Stack Overflow... :D

Answer (score 2):

Plan your CSS well. You can use `setTimeout` to add a class and make the change.

```js
setTimeout(function () {
  document.body.classList.add("after");
}, 1000);
```

```css
.header {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}
.sub-header {
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
}

.after .header {
  display: none;
}

.after .sub-header {
  width: 100%;
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  I need be removed not hided from DOM after 1 second
</div>

<div class="sub-header">
  I need be 100% after 1 second
</div>
```

Comment: display: none; Does not remove element from the DOM.

Comment: @PavelStaselun Ah.. Okay.. So this is just for hiding then... :D

Comment: it is possible remove a div or html element with just css? or need js for this?

Comment: @noob-fella Removing elements require JavaScript or DOM Interaction. CSS cannot do that.

Answer (score 0):

```js
setTimeout(
  () => {
    const elHeader = document.querySelector('.header');
    const elSubHeader = document.querySelector('.sub-header');
    elHeader.parentNode.removeChild(elHeader);
    elSubHeader.classList.add('sub-header_wide');
  },
  1000
);
```

```css
.header {
  background: red;
  width:30%;
}
.sub-header {
  background: blue;
  transition: width 0.3s;
  width:70%;
}
.sub-header_wide {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
 I need be removed not hided from DOM after 1 second
</div>

<div class="sub-header">
 I need be 100% after 1 second
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use settimeout()

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('div.header').remove();
  $('div.sub-header').css("width: 100%");  
  $('div.sub-header').slideDown("300")
}, 1000);
```

The 1000 is calculated in milliseconds